# angularjs http get request faild loading url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http-headers

i have simple angular code to reading json api from url :
http://sepehr360.com/Flight/FlightSearchGrouped?str={%22Browser%22:%22TestAndroid%22,%22CookieGuid%22:%22%22,%22CredentialPassword%22:%22%22,%22CredentialUserName%22:%22%22,%22CurencyType%22:%22IRR%22,%22CurrentUICulture%22:%22fa-ir%22,%22From%22:%22SYZ%22,%22IntervalDay%22:0,%22IsCancelAvail%22:false,%22IsDirectContract%22:false,%22IsFlightContinuous%22:false,%22IsLogin%22:true,%22IsOnlineSupport%22:false,%22IsTour%22:false,%22Language%22:%22fa%22,%22PageSize%22:10,%22Passenger%22:%22%22,%22PassengerItem%22:%22%22,%22RecordId%22:1,%22SortOrder%22:1,%22StartDate%22:%221396/3/15%22,%22To%22:%22IKA,THR%22,%22UserHostAddress%22:%22%22,%22UserInfoId%22:%22%22,%22UserName%22:%22Mobile360%22,%22getTwoWay%22:false}

when i get this url by browser its work and give json data 
and i use this angular code to reading that url

```js
/**
 * Created by ZeroL on 27/05/2017.
 */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myController' ,function($scope,$http){

 }}
    var $seplink = "sepehr360.com/Flight/FlightSearchGrouped?str={"Browser":"TestAndroid","CookieGuid":"","CredentialPassword":"","CredentialUserName":"","CurencyType":"IRR","CurrentUICulture":"fa-ir","From":"SYZ","IntervalDay":0,"IsCancelAvail":false,"IsDirectContract":false,"IsFlightContinuous":false,"IsLogin":true,"IsOnlineSupport":false,"IsTour":false,"Language":"fa","PageSize":10,"Passenger":"","PassengerItem":"","RecordId":1,"SortOrder":1,"StartDate":"1396/3/15","To":"IKA,THR","UserHostAddress":"","UserInfoId":"","UserName":"Mobile360","getTwoWay":false}";
    var $seplink1 = "data.json";

    $http.get($seplink)
        .success(function(response){
        $scope.myData = response;
    }

    );
    
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
Search : <input title="search" type="text" value="" ng-model="search"/>

<table border=1>
<tr ng-repeat="data in myData.FlightList">

    <td><img src="http://sepehr360.ir/{{data.AirLineImage}}" alt="ar"></td>
    <td>{{data.AirLineTitle}}</td>
    <td>{{data.FormatedPrice}}</td>

<td>  <a href="http://sepehr360.com{{data.FlightItems[0].FlightInfo.AgencyAddress}}">get this thicket</a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and i see result with no access info 
but i try to save url data to data.js on local and code works very well 
please help me to reading json data from this url with http 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JSON.stringify on the JSON object and then concatenating it to the URL?

Like this:

```
var $seplink = "simpleUrl";

var $jsonObject = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

var URL = $sepLink + $jsonObject;

$http.get($seplink)
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.myData = response;
    }
```

Also, could you add information about the error you're getting?

Comment: YE BUT DOMContentLoaded -> isToastRequested:false
ReferenceError: jsonObject is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/New%20folder%20(2)/js.js:8:38)...

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid string literal

```
"sepehr360.com/Flight/FlightSearchGrouped?str={"Browser":"TestAndroid","CookieGuid":"","CredentialPassword":"","CredentialUserName":"","CurencyType":"IRR","CurrentUICulture":"fa-ir","From":"SYZ","IntervalDay":0,"IsCancelAvail":false,"IsDirectContract":false,"IsFlightContinuous":false,"IsLogin":true,"IsOnlineSupport":false,"IsTour":false,"Language":"fa","PageSize":10,"Passenger":"","PassengerItem":"","RecordId":1,"SortOrder":1,"StartDate":"1396/3/15","To":"IKA,THR","UserHostAddress":"","UserInfoId":"","UserName":"Mobile360","getTwoWay":false}"
```

You need to use single quotes (`'`) to encapsulate the literal:

```
'sepehr360.com/Flight/FlightSearchGrouped?str={"Browser":"TestAndroid","CookieGuid":"","CredentialPassword":"","CredentialUserName":"","CurencyType":"IRR","CurrentUICulture":"fa-ir","From":"SYZ","IntervalDay":0,"IsCancelAvail":false,"IsDirectContract":false,"IsFlightContinuous":false,"IsLogin":true,"IsOnlineSupport":false,"IsTour":false,"Language":"fa","PageSize":10,"Passenger":"","PassengerItem":"","RecordId":1,"SortOrder":1,"StartDate":"1396/3/15","To":"IKA,THR","UserHostAddress":"","UserInfoId":"","UserName":"Mobile360","getTwoWay":false}'
```

Or escape the double quotes (`"`) that appear in the string

```
"sepehr360.com/Flight/FlightSearchGrouped?str={\"Browser\":\"TestAndroid\"......"
```

Also, the JavaScript code that you've posted is invalid. You have two closing curly brackets (`}}`) characters after the controller declaration that are out of place.

Comment: thanks but :( header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be storing the data of the response which holds the actual data returned by your server.

`$scope.myData = response.data`

Comment: thanks but not work and error:header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed

Comment: @EhsanSattari Seems like you are making a cross origin request. The server doesn't allow requests from the URL `localhost:63342`. Make sure the destination server (`sepehr360.com`) supports CORS.

Comment: yes because I get this json with  the browser and its work perfect but when I change URL it has an error I don't know what is CORS

Comment: If you don't own the server, then there's nothing much you can do about it. You can read more about CORS here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS